Why would email transmission change the 6-char sequence "0rom "?
According to the Ubuntu uuencode manpage: Specifically, email cannot handle binary data and will often even insert a character when the six character sequence "0rom " is seen.
Is (or was) that even true? And why would that be the case? I suspect some historical reason, which is why I ask the question here.

I notice that the sequence 0rom  is actually 5 characters. I wonder if the manpage intended to say something like >From 

Can you link the man page version that says this? I don't see it in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uuencode.1p.html

I see it here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/uuencode.1.html

As the answers say, it's From at the beginning of the line.  You used to find printed books or published academic papers where you'd see ">From" at the beginning of a paragraph.  (Probably still some on Google Books, actually ...)

The text quoted in the question can be found on this web page. If you download the troff source (conveniently linked at the top of the page as uuencode.1.gz), you'll see that the raw manpage says
insert a character when the six character sequence "\nFrom " is seen.

The groff documentation here says that \n followed by a letter interpolates the value of the register with that name, and "If the register is undefined, it is created and assigned a value of ‘0’".
So it's just a bug in the man page. The correct statement is that some email (and Usenet) software will munge the five characters "From " at the start of a line (usually by adding > before F), because the Unix mbox format made the dubious decision to use that character sequence to mark the start of a new message.

What would the "non-dubious" decision have been?

@cjs some kind of framing akin to HTTP's chunked encoding, in which you get the length of the message, then the message, then the length of the next message, etc. That way you're not interpreting the whole contents of each message to figure out whether it's actually the start of the next. They can be forgiven for not having invented maildir or MH or sqlite in the 1970s, but real messages with paragraphs beginning "From" would have been an immediately obvious problem.

They can only be "forgiven" in the sense that any programmer can be forgiven for doing something quick and dirty and not thinking carefully about the consequences. Personally, I'm not so forgiving.

@hobbs Interesting that you point out the big advantage of your proposed encoding but not the big disadvantage. I'm always a bit suspicious of proposals that simply say, "X is better" rather than "X is better in these ways, but also has these costs." (Personally, I see their decision as not really all that "dubious" given that they were willing to put up with even bigger problems with the mbox format that you also somehow don't seem to mention, ones that might be worsened by your suggestion.)

@MichaelKay So when you first saw the mbox format, you did an analysis of the consequences and thought, "it's possible that someone writing nroff/troff source and didn't properly understand escaping there would write a manpage that didn't render correctly," and felt that the better solution was not to have people just write manpages in correct syntax, but do an expensive rework of the mbox format? I'm doubting it.

@cjs Any format that creates an ambiguity will always, objectively, be worse than one that doesn't. There may be some compromises to do, in terms of data size for example, but ambiguity should simply be unacceptable. The non-dubious descision would have been to choose a non-ambiguous format.

"NOTES This manual page was AutoGen-erated from the uuencode option definitions." it's somehow ironic how a tool used to escape binary content had in turn its help text garbled by a tool not handling escaping correctly

@dim Except the format doesn't create any ambiguity, any more than the bit-stuffing used in the USB or Bluetooth protocol from the keyboard you're typing on does.

@cjs The primary issue is that while mbox transforms \nFrom  to \n>From , it does not transform \n>From  to \n>>From  etc. Therefore it is not possible to tell if a sequence \n>From  was originally From or >From. That makes it ambiguous, as when reading the mbox, it is not possible to reverse the process.

@cjs I was heavily involved in X.400 projects in the 1980s, and therefore very aware of the deficiencies of the cheap-and-cheerful internet email standards that won the day because of their simplicity and low cost. We thought the standards were so bad they would never catch on, and of course we were wrong.

@Ben Some software did escape >From to >>From. Wikipedia says so, and I remember it being common in the wild. If all software had escaped that way when writing and de-escaped when reading then there would have been no problem, but there was no standardization.

@cjs I can't guess what disadvantage you see in the length-counting approach.

@benrg It was over twenty years ago, and what you say rings a bell. I am sure some software when storing messages did do that, but as you say it was not universal.   It was also common for providers to switch software or migrate mboxes, so the mbox may have a mix.    The main practical problem for my job at the time was that it broke S/MIME signatures, as humans can cope with this readily but cryptographic systems cannot.

I notice that the sequence 0rom  is actually 5 characters. I wonder if the manpage intended to say something like >From 
E-mail software sometimes stores multiple e-mail messages together in a single text file called the mbox format. This format uses a line beginning with From  to mark the beinning of a stored e-mail message. In order to actually have a line beginning with From  in the content of an e-mail message, there has some kind of transformation rules used, called From-munging. If the transformation rules create any ambiguous situations, then when the message is re-opened, the content of the e-mail might be changed from how it was originally composed.
For example, if you wrote an e-mail that contained the following:
From the mountains to the prairies
To the oceans white with foam

The next time you opened the e-mail it might look like this:
>From the mountains to the prairies
To the oceans white with foam

Or if someone quoted the lines like this:
>From the mountains to the prairies
>To the oceans white with foam

it might look like this when they re-open the e-mail:
From the mountains to the prairies
>To the oceans white with foam

I don't think any e-mail transmission servers need to do this transformation, only e-mail client software that you use to read and save your e-mails. However if anyone copies content from a previous e-mail and their e-mail client didn't have a fully reversible transformation, then you might see these kinds of problems even if your e-mail client and the e-mail transmission path itself has no problems.

Mail transmission servers do often perform this munging on the recipient side, as traditionally they're the ones that initially deposit the message in the user's /var/spool/mail/xxx mbox file for the client software to see.

From-munging would have worked perfectly well if it had been implemented consistently. First of all, it's only an issue while the message is actually in an mbox. So, when putting the message in the mbox, you add one '>' to any line matching /^>*From/, and when taking the message out of the mbox, you delete one '>' from any line matching /^>+From/. No one would ever have noticed.
